# Prevent dynamically created onclick event from prematurely firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm working with a small library that [records audio in the browser](https://github.com/welll/record-encode-audio-from-browser) and uploads it to the server, but want to give the user the option to upload to browser upon button click.

Most of the library is imported to the html page, so the function I want to call, and it's parameters aren't available on the page.

Within the function that calls the 'upload' function, I tried just assigning the function call to an onclick event:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile(buf, 'mp3');
```

With the HTML being:

```
<a href='#' id="clickMe" class="btn btn-default">Upload</a>
```

But it was firing prematurely, I guess because the function is being 'evaluated'. The library uses jQuery and I tried adding `e.preventDefault()`    and `e.stopPropagation()` to the outer function, neither of which worked.

Notices that when I assigned an anonymous function it didn't get called, so am using:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function(){
        endFile(buf, 'mp3');
        }
```

Which seems to be working. Could someone please explain why, and by all means let me know any reasons why this might be an inadvisable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your function is firing prematurely is that you're actually *invoking it* when you mean to be assigning it.

Change this...

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile(buf, 'mp3');
```

To this...

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {
  endFile(buf, 'mp3');
};
```

Or this...

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile.bind(this, buf, 'mp3');
```

To explain further- `endFile(buf, 'mp3')` actually calls the function. So rather than assigning your function as an onclick-handler, you're invoking it and assigning its return value.

Comment: Ah. I had actually tried `.apply` and thought about `.bind`, but ended up going elsewhere with it.

Comment: Yeah, `.apply` and `.call` also invoke the function. `.bind` wraps it in another function that ensures a specific runtime scope, so it would work for your purposes here.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript see's any function expression `endFile(buf, 'mp3')` whether it's assigned to a variable or handler as just that, an "expression" so it calls it right away.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that it is `evaluating` the function method.

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile(buf, 'mp3');
```

Similar to:

```
var returnValue = endFile(buf, 'mp3');
```

Rather you want to set the `onclick` to a `reference` of the function `endFile`.

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile
```

**Although** there needs to be a binding of the parameters you are wanting to pass at the time of the event.  This will depend on your use case and scope of these values.

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile.bind(buf, 'mp3')
```

You are not incorrect in creating an anonymous function, but the alternative is the same.

```js
function endFile(typeOfFile) {
  var buffer = this;
  console.log(buffer, typeOfFile);
  return true;
}
var buf = 'some buffer value';
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = endFile.bind(buf, 'mp3');
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: brian beat me to it, but there you go!